# PHP and SQL: what do the 'am' and 'w' mean in this query?

Tags: php, sql

I have a quick question about this PHP function here.
What is the `am` after the SELECT query?
Also what does `w` mean in this query?

```
function download_redirect_torrent($winner_id)
{
    global $db, $setts;
    $output = array('url' => null, 'redirect' => false, 'display' => null);
    $winner_id = intval($winner_id);
    $media_details = $db->get_sql_row(
        "SELECT 
            am.*, w.is_dd, w.dd_active, w.dd_active_date 
        FROM  
            " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media am, " . DB_PREFIX . "winners w 
        WHERE 
            am.auction_id=w.auction_id AND w.winner_id=" . $winner_id . " AND am.media_type=4"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to MySQL aliases.

`winners w`, here `w` represent the winners table

so instead of writing:

```
winners.is_add, winners.dd_active_date
```

you can write in short:

```
w.is_add, w.dd_active_date
```

and the same goes for `auction_media am`.

Answer (score 5):

The `am` and the `w` are table aliases, effectively abbreviations for the table names localized to this one query.

They're specified at:

```
FROM 
    " . DB_PREFIX . "auction_media am, " . DB_PREFIX . "winners w WHERE
```

Some people would put an AS between the table name and the alias.

Answer (score 3):

Here  `w.` and `am.` are alias of table `winners` and `auction_media`. Let assume if there is any field same in both table and we are showing that so this alias will helpful to differentiate them.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`am` is an alias for `auction_media` talbe and `w` is an alias for `winner` table. Basically am in the query specifies the table to query from. In join queries to avoid any conflict between fields in two tables, it is best to use the table names, and aliasing is just a way to make it easier for longer table names.